# Restler authentication class and versioning

Tags: authentication, restler

I'm experiencing problems with versioning and authentication class in Restler version 3.0.0rc4.

In the index.php file the authentication class and a User class are added like this:

```
Defaults::$useUrlBasedVersioning = true;
$r->setAPIVersion(2);
$r->addAuthenticationClass('OAuth2');
$r->addAPIClass('User');
```

The authentication class looks like this:

```
namespace v2;
use Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate;
class OAuth2 implements iAuthenticate
{
    ...
}
```

The User class looks like this:

```
namespace v2;
class User
{
    ...
}
```

Both classes are placed in a v2 folder.

Calling the authentication class (to get a token) is no problem. When the User class is called, an internal server error is encountered due to the fact that Restler can't initialize the authentication class in Restler->authenticate. The class being initialized is "OAuth2" and it should be "v2\OAuth2".

A possible solution is to add te authentication class like this:

```
$r->addAuthenticationClass('v2\\OAuth2');
```

The problem that appears with this solution is that the Resources class outputs both a v1 and a v2 url for the authentication class while the class only exists in v2:

- v1/resources/oauth2-v2.json shows an api path: "/v1/oauth2/access_token.{format}"
- v2/resources/oauth2-v2.json shows an api path: "/v2/oauth2/access_token.{format}"

Can anyone shed some light on this?
Is it possible to use a different authentication class for each version of the api?
How comes the Resources class shows a v1 and a v2 path for the authentication class while only the v2 path exists?

Comment: We are looking into it and will soon come back with a fix

Comment: Any news on this @Luracast?

Comment: RC5 has the fix, try it out!